# How can I create a rain effect?

Tags: box2d, andengine

I'm making a game in which I want a rain effect, like rain is coming and game play normally.

Comment: Nikhil, although you managed to get answers this time, your question is not very good. Future questions should include more description of what you want and information about what you've tried.

Comment: who are u , r u owner of this site ? @Byte56

Comment: I'm not the owner Nikhil, just trying to help you create better questions in the future. The better you make your questions, the more likely you are to get help. You're only helping yourself by improving them. Additionally, lashing out at people who down vote your questions isn't going to help you get answers either, and such comments are not welcome on this site. I've marked your other comment as such.

Comment: This is a community-managed Q&A site, so Byte56 isn't the owner per-se but he gained enough reputation here to advise you to try to improve your questions. Check the FAQ for details of how this site works, espeecially the part about [etiquette](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette).

Comment: oops so sorry guys, acctually m little bit frastrated on making game that's y i wrote that comment , again sorry , and thanx for giving me suggestion :)@lorancou

Comment: What kind of game environment are you thinking of?  3D? 2D side scroller?  Top down view?

Comment: @TimHolt : i am using Andengine with Box2d game for 2d games

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to create a rain effect in andengine.

1. You can use sprite for rain drop and generate sprite at random position in the screen of the device. This will create a illusion of rain.
2. You can use a particle for creating rain effect. You have to generate particle randomly on the screen.

Comment: +1 for ur Answer man, but i don't have to much repution to make it up thanx 4 reply , r u talking about this link http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/ParticleSystemSimpleExample.java for particle for creating rain effect

Comment: yes Nikhil I am talking about that type of particle effect but you have to create manually rain type particle effect. I suggest that you use point partcile which create nice effect for you. For giving random position to particle you can use method particleEmmiter.setCenter()

Comment: Thanx a lot its working :) r u a android game developer with andengine + Box2d ? @Siddharth

Answer (score 4):

While this isn't how, it should be noted that: (this will help with speed)
You almost never see rain by itself, you only see it when it hits the ground or passes through a lit object (like a light post).
The simplest way to mimic rain without drawing any rain particles is to add fog to the world and add raindrops to the world, with maybe a few rain streaks. That will give you more realistic rain IMO. While this effect works better in 3D (you can see it discussed here: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150922154629/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/04/01/motogp-wet-weather-effects.aspx)), if done right it could probably still look good in 2D